# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: text % unknown

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to use [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)'s function :trigram to find names similar to what I store in my DB. Unfortunately, as I'm still learning SQL, this error is a bit too much for me to handle at the moment.

My Card model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :spelled_like,
                  :against => :name,
                  :using => :trigram
end
```

What I try to do in rails C:

```
2.4.1 :005 > c = "Timeslream Navigator"
 => "Timeslream Navigator" 
2.4.1 :006 > Card.spelled_like(c)
  Card Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN (SELECT "cards"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("cards"."name"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Timeslream' || ' ''') && to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Navigator' || ' ''')), 0)) AS rank FROM "cards" WHERE (((coalesce("cards"."name"::text, '')) % 'Timeslream Navigator'))) AS pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3 ON "cards"."id" = pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3.pg_search_id ORDER BY pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3.rank DESC, "cards"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % unknown
LINE 1: ...rds" WHERE (((coalesce("cards"."name"::text, '')) % 'Timeslr...
```

To clarify - the answer should be Times**TR**eam Navigator (and it does exist in my DB)

Postgres gives me a hint:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN (SELECT "cards"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("cards"."name"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Timeslream' || ' ''') && to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Navigator' || ' ''')), 0)) AS rank FROM "cards" WHERE (((coalesce("cards"."name"::text, '')) % 'Timeslream Navigator'))) AS pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3 ON "cards"."id" = pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3.pg_search_id ORDER BY pg_search_6ac9a32c0ca8e84e5bf0c3.rank DESC, "cards"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
```

But when I try to call it I get another error that doesn't tell me much at this point:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
  "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN (SELECT "cards"."id" AS 
                              ^
```

Card schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_05_31_102526) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
    enable_extension "plpgsql"
    enable_extension "pg_trgm"

  create_table "cards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "set"
    t.float "price"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "type_line"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your schema for the `cards` table?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf Added :)

Comment: did you install the trigram extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question:

- [pg_search is awesome!](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)
- In order to use trigram function you obviously have to install it.
- My problem was, I installed it directly in psql, but did not run a proper migration inside my Rails app.

Here's the migration snippet that allowed me to fix my issue and start enjoying trigram's amazing functionality:

```
class InstallPgTrgmContribPackage < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP EXTENSION pg_trgm;"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a bit different. Even though my extension was already installed, I would get this error prod AWS environments but not the lower ones. So I dropped the extension and re-created it.
 That worked.  Here was my error:

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown <%
> text Caused by the pg_search gem using trigrams.

Alternatively you can disable using trigrams, but I wanted to keep them, so I kept researching